# redimensionar imagen conforme pasan los dias "contador"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un contador hacia atrás que debajo lleva una imagen de un planeta y me gustaría que, a medida que se va acabando el tiempo, la imagen fuera creciendo unos 5 px por cada lado. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar o dar alguna pista de como hacerlo en JavaScript?

Este código es el que utilizo para el contador:

```
$("#countdownDays").countdown("2017/01/31", function(event) {
    $(this).text( event.strftime('%D') );
});


      <div class="info-item">
    <div>
        <div id="countdownDays" class="contador">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="info-text">DAYS</P>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="item">:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="countdownHours" class="contador">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="info-text">HOURS</P>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="item">:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="countdownMin" class="contador">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="info-text">MINS</P>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="item">:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="countdownSecs" class="contador">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="info-text">SECS</P>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="../Projecto_contador/imagenes/shutterstock_311198186.jpg" class="image" id="resize">
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Has de pegar algo de código que tengas, por ejemplo especificando como haces ese contador.

Comment: lo he estado haciendo en javascript con jquery... el contador lo hice con jquery pero redimensionar no e llegado a nada. porque no se ni por donde empezar. soy aun novato en javascript y aun me quedan pegarme muchas hostias.

Comment: $("#countdownDays")
    .countdown("2017/01/31", function(event) {
        $(this).text(
            event.strftime('%D')
        );
    });  Este codigo es el que utilizo para el contador

Comment: El código que intentó , agregar en su pregunta mediante el enlace editar.

Comment: Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 5):

Lo que quieres hacer va a depender mucho de uno o dos factores:

- El tamaño de inicio/fin de la imagen
- El intervalo de tiempo en el que se va a realizar el crecimiento

Si el tamaño de inicio es el tamaño real de la imagen, vas a necesitar definir un intervalo de tiempo en el que se harán los incrementos de +5px/día (ahora mismo tienes la fecha de destino X, te haría falta una fecha de origen Y, para poder calcular el crecimiento).

Si el tamaño final es el tamaño real de la imagen, entonces no necesitas un intervalo, porque ya viene limitado por el tamaño de la imagen y sería tamaño/5 días.

Una vez tomada esa decisión, te va a quedar un número que representará el número de días en los que la imagen va a crecer. A partir de ahí, la lógica es simple (aunque cambiará ligeramente de un método al otro).

Yo me voy a basar en que el tamaño de inicio es el tamaño real de la imagen y va creciendo conforme pasan los días y se acerca el contador a cero. El algortimo sería algo como esto:

1. Obtén el número de días de la cuenta atrás (voy a llamarlo Restantes) usando la función que ya tienes de `countDown`.
2. Obtén el número de días en los que la imagen cambiará de tamaño (voy a llamarlo Totales). Este valor realmente lo debes tener desde antes.
3. Si `Totales <= Restantes` quiere decir que aún no hemos llegado el tiempo en el que la imagen crece, así que no se haría nada. Salta al paso 6.
4. Si `Totales > Restantes`, quiere decir que la cuenta atrás ya comenzó/terminó (`countDown` devuelve 0 si la cuenta atrás ya acabó), entonces:

   1. Calcula el incremento total, que sería `tamaño imagen + Totales*5`
   2. Cambia el tamaño de la imagen para que sea el nuevo tamaño
5. Fin

Y el código podría ser algo así:

```js
// definimos los días totales
var diasTotales = 100;

// tamaño real de la imagen
var tamaReal = 0;

$("#countdownDays").countdown("2017/01/31", function(event) {

  // obtenemos los días restantes
  var diasRestantes = parseInt(event.strftime('%D'));

  // los escribimos por pantalla
  $(this).text( diasRestantes );

  // si estamos dentro del rango de crecimiento diasRestantes < diasTotales
  if (diasRestantes < diasTotales) {
    // si no se ha calculado antes, obtenemos el tamaño real de la imagen
    // para evitar que se recalcule el tamaño una vez redimensionada la imagen
    if (tamaReal == 0) { tamaReal = $("#resize").width(); }

    // calculamos el nuevo tamaño
    var nuevoTama = tamaReal + (diasTotales - diasRestantes)*5;
    $("#resize").width( nuevoTama );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-item">
  <div>
    <div id="countdownDays" class="contador">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="info-text">DAYS</P>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Zxwanjt.jpg" class="image" id="resize">
</div>
```